# Trouble to deploy flask application on heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, deployment, gunicorn

I'm having trouble to deploy my flask application on heroku,
my directory tree is looking like down below:

```
├── app
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── routes.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── storage.db
│   └── templates
├── migrations
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── runtime.txt
```

```
  $ cat runtime
  python-3.8.5

  $ cat Procfile 
  web: gunicorn: app:app
```

I'm quite confuse on the configuration of Procfile, should I call run.py (The archive I use to call locally with "flask run") or app (The folder where **init**.py calls flask instance and sql_alchemy instance)?

Anyway, both configurations returned the error below:

---

$ **heroku logs --tail**

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn: app:app`
app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn:: command not found
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

gunicorn is already configured at requirements.py

Comment: Assuming your `run.py` is the entry point of your app and you have named your flask instance as `app` , your Procfile should look like `web: gunicorn run:app`

Comment: Thank you @Aditya it worked! Why don't you answer below instead of just comment? Then I'll mark as best answer, it should help other people :)

Comment: You are welcome:). Honestly I don't know why I haven't wrote it as an answer. But anyways I am writing it as an answer now so that other people could also benifit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `run.py` is the entry point of your app and you have named your flask instance as `app` , your Procfile should look like:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

It is because in your Procfile the first argument must be the name of your main file or entry file from where you are running your website and the second is the name of your flask instance itself. Atleast it is with the case of gunicorn and heroku.